# Australian Phone Number Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a web form that should only accept valid Australian phone numbers.
I have `data-type="phone"` on the phone field though the `parsley.js` file does not recognize Australian number formats.
I have attempted to edit the `parsley.js` file without any success. Does anyone have the code to accept Australian number formats?
Failing that, how could I make the phone number field a required digit field that also accepts spaces and a minimum of 8 digits? `data-type"digit"` doesn't seem to allow any spaces.

Comment: This may have already been answered here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032040/parsley-js-telephone-digits-input-validating-with-spaces

Answer (score 1):

If you want want to go with all HTML5 look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bud68oho/2/

This fiddle uses the `required` and `pattern` attributes to validate the form. The `required` attribute does not allow the form to post if the input is not filled in. The `pattern` attribute allows you to implement regex for matching. If the input does not meet the requirements of the regex then the form will not post.

The only gotcha with this approach is browser compatibility. Make sure to test this method with your target browsers. The above example works in the latest version of IE and Chrome, I am unable to do any further testing.

Answer (score -1):

I have wriiten a small code snippet.
http://plnkr.co/edit/InZyHRexEJ0fMdvrAAZK?p=preview

I wrote this pattern keeping in mind that the telephone format is "+61012341234". You can use spaces in the pattern if required.

If you want to validate once the value has been entered, then you can call this function on 'onblur' event on the text box.

the regular expression for accepting 8 digits and spaces is

if +61 is mandatory then the regExp could be "/^(+61)[0-9 ]{8,12}$/" or else "/^[0-9 ]{8,12}$/".

Here min is 8 and max is 12 digits including spaces.

HTML Code

```
<body>    
<input type="text" id="phNo">
<span id="demo"></span>
<button onclick="validateFields()">Validate</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
function validateFields() {

var str = document.getElementById("phNo").value;

var patt = /^(\+61)[0-9]{1}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$/;
var res = patt.test(str);
var temp = "corect phone mnumber.";
 if(res!=true){
   temp = "wrong phone mnumber.";
 }else{
   //here you can post the data from script.
 }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temp;
}
```

If the requirement is not fulfilled, please let me know. I will try my best.